# Stream Multicasting - read a stream once but process it different ways, with minimal buffering

Tags: .net, asynchronous, stream, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

For scalability and to conserve resources, it is best to avoid reading an entire input stream into memory, but instead try to process it as a stream, reading small chunks at a time.  This is easy to accomplish in .NET when you have one thing you want to do with the data, like read it from a web request and save it to a file.  Easy example:

```
input.CopyTo(output); // reads chunks of 4096 bytes and writes them to `output`
```

But when I want to do multiple things with that data, it's quite a bit trickier.  For example, I want to:

- Count the length of a stream that doesn't support the `Length` property.  We can do this with a custom `DummyStream` that does nothing with the data written to it except keep track of the length.
- [Calculate the MD5 of the stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Figure out the Mime type of the data.  [FindMimeFromData](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.FindMimeFromData) needs only the first 256 bytes of the stream.
- Save the whole [stream to the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

... but only do so with a single pass over the input stream, with minimal use of buffering.

I am sure that this is possible.  I could probably coordinate multiple threads, with one thread doing the actual reading from the input stream and other threads for each of the "processing" tasks I want to perform.  But that could easily get rather complicated and fragile if not done just right.

My question is this:

- Do I have to use multiple threads?  I would love some kind of co-routine solution where all of the processing is interleaved on one thread.
- Are there ways that I could leverage C#'s `async` features, or Reactive Extensions to make this solution simpler?

I'm having trouple wrapping my brain around this one.  I'm looking for guidance on the best (clean, maintainable, efficient use of computer resources) way to accomplish this, especially in light of newer technologies like the TPL, `async`, and RX.

---

This is an example of the syntax I'm envisioning:

```
public static void Multicast(this Stream input, params Action<Stream>[] processingActions)
{
    // TODO: ??? complicated stream multicasting logic goes here. ???
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
long length;
byte[] md5;
string mimeType;
int uploadId;

input.Multicast(
    s => length = GetLength(s),
    s => md5 = CalculateMd5(s),
    s => mimeType = DetermineMimeType(s, filename, mimeTypeAsReportedByClient)
    s => uploadId = SaveToDatabase(s)
);
```

And here's an example of one of the processing actions:

```
private static byte[] CalculateMd5(Stream input)
{
    return MD5.Create().ComputeHash(input);
}
```

Comment: Added a code example.

Comment: So, in other words, you want to be able to work with the stream using `Read()`, not write a custom stream with overridden `Write()`, right?

Comment: Correct.  I'm sure the solution is going to require creating some kind of custom stream, but it needs to be a stream that can be read from so that existing .NET functionality, like `ComputeHash` and Sql Client's support for streams, can be easily reused.

Comment: That is a key requirement; you should edit it into the question as it restricts solutions considerably.

Comment: Perhaps "needs" is too strong a word here.  I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to accomplish all of the things I want in one solution (single-threaded co-routine is probably a fantasy), but there probably still is one best way to solve the problem.  Some compromises will likely have to be made.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to take a shot at an Rx implementation. Here's what I got so far. It doesn't do any DB writes, but it does compute the length, MD5 hash, and mimetype with only one pass over the file and minimal buffering.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace RxTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var expectedValues = ReadExpectedValuesDirectly("demo.txt");

            new FileInfo("demo.txt")
                .ReadAsObserveable(4096)
                .ToFileData()
                .Subscribe(observed => Compare(expectedValues, observed));
        }

        private static void Compare(FileData expected, FileData observed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            WriteLine("expected", expected);
            WriteLine("observed", observed);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Debug.Assert(observed.Length == expected.Length);
            Debug.Assert(BitConverter.ToString(observed.Hash) == BitConverter.ToString(expected.Hash));
            Debug.Assert(observed.MimeType == expected.MimeType);
        }

        private static void WriteLine(string prefix, FileData observed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:N0}   {2}   {3}",
                prefix,
                observed.Length,
                observed.MimeType,
                BitConverter.ToString(observed.Hash).Replace("-", ""));
        }

        private static FileData ReadExpectedValuesDirectly(string fileName)
        {
            return new FileData
            {
                Length = new FileInfo(fileName).Length,
                Hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)),
                MimeType = FileDataExtensions.FindMimeType(GetFirst256Bytes(fileName))
            };
        }

        private static byte[] GetFirst256Bytes(string path)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[256];

                if (stream.Length >= 256)
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
                else
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int) stream.Length);

                return buffer;
            }
        }
    }

    public class FileData
    {
        public long Length { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FileDataExtensions
    {
        public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadAsObserveable(this FileInfo file, int bufferSize)
        {
            return Observable.Create<byte[]>(observer =>
            {
                using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
                {
                    return stream.ReadAsObservable(bufferSize).Subscribe(observer);
                }
            });
        }

        public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadAsObservable(this Stream stream, int bufferSize)
        {
            // TODO: Add scheduling/canceling
            return Observable.Create<byte[]>(observer =>
            {
                var block = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(block, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
                {
                    if (bytesRead == bufferSize)
                        observer.OnNext(block);
                    else
                    {
                        var lastBlock = new byte[bytesRead];
                        Array.Copy(block, lastBlock, bytesRead);
                        observer.OnNext(lastBlock);
                        observer.OnCompleted();
                    }
                }

                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }

        public static IObservable<FileData> ToFileData(this IObservable<byte[]> file)
        {
            return Observable.Create<FileData>(observer =>
            {
                var counter = 0;
                var connectable = file
                    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine())
                    .Do(_ => Console.Write(++counter))
                    .Publish();

                var combineSub = Observable.CombineLatest(
                    connectable.TotalLength(),
                    connectable.ComputeHash(MD5.Create()),
                    connectable.FindMimeType(),
                    (length, hash, mimeType) => new FileData
                    {
                        Hash = hash,
                        Length = length,
                        MimeType = mimeType
                    })
                    .Subscribe(observer);

                var connectSub = connectable.Connect();

                return new CompositeDisposable(combineSub, connectSub);
            });
        }

        public static IObservable<long> TotalLength(this IObservable<byte[]> file)
        {
            return file
                .Do(block => Console.Write("\tLength()"))
                .Select(block => block.LongLength)
                .Sum();
        }

        public static IObservable<byte[]> ComputeHash(this IObservable<byte[]> file, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            return Observable.Create<byte[]>(observer =>
                file
                    .Do(block => Console.Write("\tComputeHash()"))
                    .Subscribe(
                        block => algorithm.TransformBlock(block, 0, block.Length, null, 0),
                        () =>
                        {
                            algorithm.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);
                            observer.OnNext(algorithm.Hash);
                            observer.OnCompleted();
                        }));
        }

        public static IObservable<string> FindMimeType(this IObservable<byte[]> file)
        {
            // this doesn't handle cases where the file is less than 256 bytes in length.
            return file
                .Do(block => Console.Write("\tFindMimeType()"))
                .Take(1)
                .Select(block =>
                {
                    var first256 = new byte[256];
                    Array.Copy(block, first256, 256);
                    return FindMimeType(first256);
                });
        }

        public static string FindMimeType(byte[] first256)
        {
            try
            {
                UInt32 unMimeType;
                FindMimeFromData(0, null, first256, 256, null, 0, out unMimeType, 0);
                var pMimeType = new IntPtr(unMimeType);
                var sMimeTypeFromFile = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pMimeType);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pMimeType);
                return sMimeTypeFromFile;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // not exactly robust exeption handling
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
            UInt32 pBC,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pwzUrl,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
            UInt32 cbSize,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pwzMimeProposed,
            UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
            out UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
            UInt32 dwReserverd
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool!  I like the way you flipped the Md5 calculation around from pull to push by using `TransformBlock` instead of `ComputeHash`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rx you could use `Observable.Create` to create an observable which reads the stream, then use `Publish` to allow multiple subscriptions to the steam without starting it yet, and then call `Connect` on the `Published` stream to get everything off and running. You could use `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` for each of the different "routes" the stream data takes to determine when, where, and how each portion of the code runs, which means you could buffer the whole stream and submit it to the database all at once, do the same for the MD5, count the stream using `Scan` or `Aggregate`, but you could also have an "route" that determines the mime-type and unsubscribes early. Plus, if you needed to synchronize these elements back together, you could use `CombineLatest`.

This question is very interesting to me, and I wish I had the time right now to post some real code examples. Unfortunately, I do not. Hopefully this gives you an idea of what operators could be used in what configurations to accomplish what you're looking for.

Here's some psuedo-code for the non-stream reading parts...

```
var connectable = ReadStreamAsObservable(stream).Publish();

var mimeType = connectable.ReadMimeTypeAsObservable();
var md5      = connectable.ReadMD5AsObservable();
var record   = connectable.SubmitToDatabaseAsObservable(myDbConnection);
var length   = connectable.Aggregate(0, (acc, x) => acc + x.Bytes.Length);

var parts = Observable.CombineLatest(mimeType, md5, length, record,
  (mimeType, md5, length, record) => new {
    MimeType = mimeType,
    MD5 = md5,
    Length = length,
    Record = record
  });

var subscription = new CompositeDisposable(
  parts.Subscribe((x) => Console.WriteLine(x)),
  connectable.Connect()
  );
```

Comment: I have almost zero knowledge about Rx, so it's going to take me some time to evaluate this answer.  I do intend to do so - please be patient with me as I go off to study http://www.introtorx.com/.

Comment: Just a warning, this could become unbounded in memory if you're reading from the stream faster than the subscribers can process it.

Comment: True, but that could happen regardless of what technology you're using to process the stream.

Comment: Also, `obs` is a perfectly acceptable name for a `ConnectableObservable`, imo. :)

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I agree, if you check the edit you'll see it was named two different things. I just chose the name that was used in the most placed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to have one input stream, multiple output streams and then copy the input to all the outputs, something like:

```
Stream input;
IList<Stream> outputs;

byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
int read;

while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    foreach (var output in outputs)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Those output streams don't have to be normal streams, they could be special streams that for example just calculate the length. They would need to override only the `Write()` method, so a custom base `Stream` could be useful:

```
public class OutputStreamBase : Stream
{
    private int length;

    public override void Flush()
    {}

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        length += count;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return length; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
}
```

This stream can be used directly as the counting stream, or to easily implement the find MIME stream.

Comment: +1: Single thread, simple.  Good stuff.  If you have streams you need to write to, this is an excellent way to approach the problem.  This could be wrapped up in a `CopyTo(params Stream[] outputs)` extension method - just like the existing `CopyTo` method, but for multiple outputs.  I think there may even be a way to generalize this for problems that need a "read" stream, too, using some special kind of stream that flips itself around.  Like `new FlippedStream(s => CalculateMd5(s))`.  Hmmm...

Comment: Why make this extend stream when all you're really doing is using a single `Action<byte[], int>`? It seems like you could just pass the function or an object with that interface. While your solution works well I know I'd be really confused if I were the next developer to pick it up needing to make changes.

Comment: @BryanAnderson How do you get the result (like the computed length or the MD5 hash) from the `Action`? Sure, you could use closure, but I think having an object for that is cleaner.

Comment: @svick Include a side effect in the action (your version does as well). Personally I'd prefer to us an interface and pass in an object that could handle the side effects and knock-on actions. I wasn't trying to be critical, I have a similar problem to OP and was just treating the answers like I would in a code review to help get to a great solution.