# Buffered stream details

Tags: c#, .net, bufferedstream

I want to explain my understanding with example. Let `stream` be any abstract buffered network stream with 4 bytes buffer. Let there be some byte-to-byte writing process (drawed like FIFO).

```
write->|    |    |    |    |----->net
```

`----->net` operation is very slow, and we want to minimize it's quantity. Here buffer helps.

```
write->|  1 |    |    |    |----->net
write->|  5 |  1 |    |    |----->net
write->| 12 |  5 |  1 |    |----->net
write->|  7 | 12 |  5 |  1 |----->net
```

Here, or, maybe, some time earlier, .NET virtual machine, or operating system, decides to complete writing operation and flushes the data:

```
write->|    |    |    |    |----->net   7 12 5 1->
```

So, `write->` operations become very fast, and, at least after lag while stream closing, data become sended to the remote host.

In the code it can be look like this:

```
using(networkStream)
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         networkStream.WriteByte(getNextByte());
```

Am I right? **If `getNextByte` operation will lag a thread,** can I count on that data will be passed to the stream stealthily (asynchroniously), **will not `WriteByte` lag all the code?** Or it will lag four times rarely? Haven't I implement some *circular buffer* to pass data to it, and launch additional thread which will read data from buffer and pass data to the network stream?

I also hope a lot that buffered network stream can increase speed of data receiving.

```
 read<-|    |  1 |  5 | 12 |<-----net <-7


 using(networkStream)
     while((b = networkStream.ReadByte()) >= 0)
         process(b);
```

**If I synchroniously get and process bytes from buffered** network **stream,** can I count on that data to the stream buffer will be transmitted by networkStream stealthily (asynchroniously), **will not `ReadByte` lag all the code?** Or it will lag four times rarely?

P.S. I know that standard `NetworkStream` stream is buffered.

---

Wanna tell about my concrete case. I have to realize **striping** of stream. I read data from stream from remote client and want to pass it to several streams to remote servers, but with **alternating** (called it *forking*) ([image a](http://yadi.sk/d/lTwhHg7oQsHx2)), like this

```
var i = 0;
while((c = inStream.Read(buf, 0, portions[i])) > 0)
{
    outStreams[i].Write(buf, 0, c);
    i = (i + 1) % outStreams.Length;
}
```

[image b](http://yadi.sk/d/lTwhHg7oQsHx2) shows *merging* process, coding in the same way.

I don't want to doom remote client to wait while program will do slow `Write` to remote servers operations. So, I tried to organize manually *backgroung* writting from network to inStream and *backgroung* reading from outStreams to network. But maybe I haven't care while I'm using buffered streams? Maybe buffered streams eliminate such breaks of read-write processes?

Comment: While it is nicely decorated, it is unclear what you are asking. *Lag all code* - what do you mean? You have to use [`DataAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) before trying to read anything and **you** have to decide what to do if data is available or not. Btw, [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) method will not block anything are you sure what `ReadByte()` (inherited from `Stream`) will do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant usual `bufferred` trait of any stream, even `BufferedStream`-wrapped streams. Maybe it was stupid. Updated the Q. I've suddenly encountered question about [Stream Multicasting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21143734/3237954), will think about it.